Bulk Processing of data in ASP.NET Core Web API with Angular
I'm using Angular 15 and an ASP.NET Core Web API. I have a use case where I need to process 1000s of records which involve querying from LDAP and updating into a database.
This whole process might take more time which might end up timing out. I'm looking for a solution which can be implemented without timing out. And also if the user navigates to the different page, I want the processing should be continued in the background and notification can be send to the client once it's over. I'm thinking about SignalR here.
I need some suggestions too.
TIA
